# Images not showing directly

Tags: html, css, new-operator

Hey so im new to programming and im trying to make a website but when i open my html file directly
it doesnt show images but when i open with vs code or brackets editor live server, it shows all the photos and pictures how can i make my index file show images without opening with editor

NOTE. i have all my png and jpg files in one folder and i specify them under src="/images/photo.jpg" i have tried ./images/photo.jpg,../images/photo.jpg,images/photo,jpg but doesnt work i also have tried giving them the full destination but still wont work

Comment: can you share the screenshot of your project structure inside editor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Its always good to define the folder path rather absolute, Hope this helps

```
<img src = "/images/test.png" alt = "Test Image" />
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but its not that this doesnt work when i live preview with editor when i do it it works perfectly but if i click the html doc raw without editor or anything it doesnt show any pictures and messes my document up i wanted to know if theres anyway it would display the way i wanted without going to the editor